# Java, Hashmap,Data Type Conversion

Tags: java, file-io, hashmap, type-conversion

I'm going to read a folder (wiki-pmi) containing text files ( 7GB in total) and put them in a hashmap. Each line of the text file are like : geophysical graduation 0.1321

I wrote the following code:

```
HashMap<String,Double> pmi = new HashMap<String,Double>();
File folder = new File("wiki-pmi");
String line;
File[] listofFiles = folder.listFiles();
for(File file: listofFiles)
{
if(file.isFile())
{
BufferedReader br1  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

while((line=br1.readLine())!=null)
{
String[] split=line.split(" ");
pmi.put(split[0]+ ","+ split[1], Double.parseDouble(split[2]));
}
}
}
```

However, After running on Eclipse I get the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at NLP.main(NLP.java:30)
```

that points (java:30) to

```
pmi.put(split[0]+ ","+ split[1], Double.parseDouble(split[3]));
```

I guess I failed to convert from String type to Double type, correct?

Comment: Shoudln't it be pmi.put(split[0]+ ","+ split[1], Double.parseDouble(split[2]));  ?

you are trying to use forutrh emelent of array with length 3 (it starts with 0)

Comment: Thanks, Any other way to put textfiles with "geophysical graduation 0.1321' in the hashmap?

Comment: I think the way you do it is correct. You can use regex but in ths case it would be more complicated then simple split()

Comment: @Barteks2x as per exception it's pointing to index 1.

Comment: Check the size of split[] before using it.  If it is not the size you expect, print it out and stop so you can see if there is bad data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, put a capacity to your map:

```
HashMap<String,Double> pmi = new HashMap<String,Double>(2000);
```

The default capacity is 16 and it doubles everytime it need to increase (16..32..64..128..256.......).

Loading everything into a map is a bad idea, you should use a temporary database.

About your conversion and optimization, can you give sample lines?

Comment: Thanks for your comment...I changed it to 2000 but not working yet. I don't get what do you mean by sample. However each line in the text file are as follows:batch batched 0.3992
                 batch batches 0.5732
                batch batching 0.4788
                    batch bath 0.1132
                   batch baths 0.1406
               batch battalion 0.1406    each line has three tokens

Answer (score 0):

Split[3] is out of bound.. 
As your string split function will return you an array of size 3 with startIndex = 0

Comment: Thanks, But it was writing error. I changed it already to 2 but still the problem remains the same.